# Sum $\text{S} = \sum_{i = 2}^{2008}{\frac{1}{a_i}},$ where $a_1 = \frac{1}{3}$ and $ a_{n + 1} = a_n^2 + a_n.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Define the sequence $\{a_n\}$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ given by $a_1 = \frac{1}{3}$ and $$ a_{n + 1} = a_n^2 + a_n.$$ Let $$\text{S} = \sum_{i = 2}^{2008}{\frac{1}{a_i}},$$
then find $\lfloor S \rfloor$ where $\lfloor X \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer lesser than or equal to $X$.

P.S.: The obvious approach would be to telescope, but as far as I can see, terms do not cancel at all and the estimation of S becomes cumbersome. I have also tried modifying it by adding $\frac{1}{4}$ to both sides and defining $b_n = a_n + \frac{1}{2}$ gives us $$b_{n + 1} = b_n^2 + \frac{1}{4}$$ 
but this doesn't help me in any way to estimate S. One can read off that the original sequence is increasing but i am unable to put an upper bound (such as a G.P.) to find [S].

Comment: What I have found is that $1/a_{n+1}=1/a_n-1/(a_n+1)$. This recursion looks interesting. I hope this would help.

Comment: @Bernard Pan it doesn't.. I've tried but then I was unable to find a closed form

Comment: @PuneetSingh I have added a new solution. Please check if it is satisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is $5$.**

Much thanks to @JohnBentin for pointing out the embarrassing flaw in my previous solution.

We may easily calculate the values of $a_2,a_3$ and $a_4$ by hand, and this gives us $\frac{4}{9}, \frac{52}{81}$ and $ \frac{6916}{6561} > 1$ respectively. 
Since all the terms in $\{a_n\}$ are positive, $a_{n+1}=a^2_n+a_n>a_n$, so the sequence is strictly increasing, which immediately allows us to conclude that $∀ \ n≥4, a_n>1$.

**Claim:** $\forall \ n \geq 4,\frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{a_{n}+1} < \frac{1}{a_n}-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}} $.

**Proof:** Equivalently, we show that $a_{n+1}>a_n+1$. But $a_{n+1}=a_{n}(a_{n}+1)>a_{n}+1$, since $a_n>1 \ \forall \ n \geq 4$, which concludes our proof.

Now, $$S=\sum_{i=2}^{2008}\frac{1}{a_i}=\sum_{k=1}^{2007}\frac{1}{a_{k+1}}$$ Here, we carry out the substitution $i=k+1$.

Thus, $$S=\sum_{k=1}^{2007}\frac{1}{a_{k+1}}=\sum_{k=1}^{2007}\frac{1}{a_k(a_{k}+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^{2007}\left(\frac{1}{a_{k}}-\frac{1}{a_k+1}\right)$$

Next, we derive both a lower and upper bound for $S$.

**Lower Bound:**

$$S=\left(\frac{1}{a_1}-\frac{1}{a_1+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_2}-\frac{1}{a_2+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_3}-\frac{1}{a_3+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_4}-\frac{1}{a_4+1}\right) + ... + \left(\frac{1}{a_{2007}}-\frac{1}{a_{2007}+1}\right) $$

$$> \left(\frac{1}{a_1}-\frac{1}{a_1+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_2}-\frac{1}{a_2+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_3}-\frac{1}{a_3+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_4}-\frac{1}{a_4+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_5}-\frac{1}{a_5}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_6}-\frac{1}{a_6}\right)+...+\left(\frac{1}{a_{2007}}-\frac{1}{a_{2007}}\right)$$

$$=\left(\frac{1}{a_1}-\frac{1}{a_1+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_2}-\frac{1}{a_2+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_3}-\frac{1}{a_3+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_4}-\frac{1}{a_4+1}\right) \approx 5.22 > 5 $$

**Upper Bound:**
This is where we make use of the above stated claim, and employ the trick of using a telescoping series.

$$S < \left(\frac{1}{a_1}-\frac{1}{a_1+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_2}-\frac{1}{a_2+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_3}-\frac{1}{a_3+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_4}-\frac{1}{a_5}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_5}-\frac{1}{a_6}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_6}-\frac{1}{a_7}\right)+...+\left(\frac{1}{a_{2007}}-\frac{1}{a_{2008}}\right)$$

$$=\left(\frac{1}{a_1}-\frac{1}{a_1+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_2}-\frac{1}{a_2+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_3}-\frac{1}{a_3+1}\right)+\frac{1}{a_4}-\frac{1}{a_{2008}}$$

$$< 5.82-\frac{1}{a_{2008}} < 6 $$

Finally, combining the above, we conclude that $S$ is strictly in-between $5$ to $6$, i.e. $\lfloor S \rfloor =5$, and we are done.

Comment: My altered proof makes use of the telescoping series to produce the upper bound.

Comment: Meanwhile, the lower bound is derived by making a lot of the terms in parantheses zero.

Comment: (1) My eyesight isn't good enough to read doubly reduced symbols. Please put Tex code between double dollars to display properly. (2) $\sum_{i=1}^na_i-b_i$ means the result of subtracting $b_i$ from $\sum_{i=1}^na_i$. The parentheses in  $\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i-b_i)$ are necessary if that is what is meant. (3) Rather than $\approx5.81$ use $<5.82$: approximation and inequality don't mix. Since you have already shown that $5<S$, you only need to point out that $5.82<6$. (4) Your method looks promising. I will look at it again when it is edited. Spell my userername without spaces to notify me.

Comment: @JohnBentin Many thanks for the feedback! Have edited accordingly.

Comment: I think the newly added parantheses around the quantity $S=\sum_{k=1}^{2007}(\frac{1}{a_{k}}-\frac{1}{a_k+1})$ is what you wanted.

Comment: To get properly sized parentheses in the displays, use the code \left( , instead of just ( , and and \right) , instead of just ) . Anyway, your proof is sound now.

Comment: Nice! It looks much better now. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I only wonder how much of calculator work went in this... Nice job to telescope though.. I didn't expect it to even happen!

Comment: Thanks! The calculator work was for the first $4$ terms of the sequence only, if you read carefully. $\left(\frac{1}{a_1}-\frac{1}{a_1+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_2}-\frac{1}{a_2+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_3}-\frac{1}{a_3+1}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{a_4}-\frac{1}{a_4+1}\right) \approx 5.22$, for example, can quickly be done by a pocket calculator.

Comment: @PuneetSingh There is also actually another very small trick I forgot to mention: Can you see why $\frac{1}{a_1}-\frac{1}{a_1+1}=\frac{1}{a_2}$, for example?

Comment: It's because the former expression is actually your $\frac{1}{a_{1+1}}$ in disguise! So even tricks like this greatly helps to simplify calculator work.

Comment: And funnily enough, the idea for telescoping stemmed from a highly erroneous solution that I originally posted. Fortunately, after some effort, I was able to adapt it to fit my new solution.

Answer (score 1):

Start from recurrence relation $a_{n+1} = a_n(a_n+1)$, it is clear if we start from any $a_1 > 0$, $a_n$ will be a strictly increasing sequence.

If for some $N$, we have $a_N = \alpha > 1$, then for all $n \ge N$, we have
$$a_{n+1} = a_{n}(a_{n}+1) \ge a_n(1+\alpha)
\quad\implies\quad \frac{1}{a_{n+1}} \le \frac{1}{a_n(1+\alpha)}$$

This implies for all $k \ge 0$, we have $\displaystyle\;a_{N+k} \le \frac{1}{a_N}\frac{1}{(1+\alpha)^k}$. As a result,
$$\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n} \le \frac{1}{a_N}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(1+\alpha)^k}
= \frac{1}{a_N}\frac{\frac{1}{1+\alpha}}{1 - \frac{1}{1+\alpha}} = \frac{1}{a_N\alpha} = \frac{1}{a_N^2}
$$
By brute force, we have
$$(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,\ldots) = (\frac13,\frac49,\frac{52}{81},\frac{6916}{6561},\frac{93206932}{43046721},\ldots)$$
Since $a_n > 1$ start at $n = 4$, we can take $N = 5$. By above argument, we have:

$$5.2182 \sim \sum_{n=2}^5 \frac{1}{a_n}
\le \sum_{n=2}^{2008} \frac{1}{a_n} < \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{a_n} \le \sum_{n=2}^5 \frac{1}{a_n} + \frac{1}{a_5^2} \sim 5.4315$$
So the answer is $5$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: As you just need to calculate [S], notice that when $a_n$>2, $a_{n+1}>3a_n$, therefore $\frac{1}{a_{n+1}}<\frac{1}{3a_n}$ then use geometric sequence, this sum is less than...

Comment: Not a good estimate though... I got better with $a_n > 1$ and then an easier calculation..  thank you for the idea anyways