# Does $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{a_n+1}$ with $a_{n+1}=a_n(a_n+1)$ and $a_1=\frac12$ have a closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion, telescopic-series

Mr Beast here. I've been working on a complicated math problem, and I obtained a recursive sequence $a_{n+1}=a_n(a_n+1)$ and that $a_1=\frac 12$. I've been thinking, is it possible to convert this to closed form, or otherwise evaluate $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{a_n+1}$?

The original question said that $a_{1}=\frac{1}{2}$ and that $a_{n+1}=a_{n}\left(a_{n}+1\right),$ asked me to prove that $\frac{1}{a_{1}+1}+\frac{1}{a_{2}+1}+\frac{1}{a_{3}+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_{n}+1}<2$ for all $n$ larger than $1 .$ I wondered if it was possible to convert into closed form to evaluate the sum definitely. I originally thought to solve it through a telescoping series, but the denominator leaves me unsure of what to do.

Comment: Look at [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A014117) (thanks to one of our very own: Robert Israel) and divide it by $4$. It's pretty likely there isn't a nice closed form.

Comment: The infinite sum does numerically seem to be 2

Comment: Related but not the same: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3644097/sum-texts-sum-i-22008-frac1a-i-where-a-1-frac13-a?noredirect=1

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$ \frac1{a_{n+1} } = \frac1{a_n(a_n+1)}=\frac{(a_n+1)-a_n}{a_n(a_n+1)} = \frac1{a_n} - \frac1{a_n+1}$$
Therefore
$$ \frac1{a_n+1}=\frac1{a_n}-\frac1{a_{n+1}}$$
Summing in $n$ gives a telescoping series,
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{a_k+1} = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{a_k}-\frac1{a_{k+1}} = \frac1{a_1} - \frac1{a_{n+1}}.$$
Plugging in $a_1=1/2$, we see that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{a_k+1} = 2 - \frac1{a_{n+1}}.$$

Note that $a_1=1/2,\ a_2=3/4,\ a_3=21/16>1$, and from that point on the equation gives
$$ a_{n+1} = a_n(a_n+1) \ge a_n+1$$
so that $a_n\to\infty$. Hence $\frac1{a_{n+1}}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, which means that
$$ \fbox{$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{a_k+1} = 2. $}$$

In particular, since $\frac1{a_n+1}>0$ for all $n$, this proves (as is the 'original question' in the comments) that the finite sum of only the first $n$ terms is strictly smaller than $2$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** show (using induction on $m$) that $$\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{1}{a_n+1}=\frac1{a_1}-\frac1{a_{m+1}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but deals with the underlying problem disclosed by OP in a comment to the question.

Consider the terms $$b_i = \frac{1}{a_i + 1}$$where $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ and $a_{i+1} = a_i^2 + a_i$:
$$b_1 = \frac{2}{3}, \,
b_2 = \frac{4}{7}, \,
b_3 = \frac{16}{37}, \,
b_4 = \frac{256}{1033}, \,
b_5 = \frac{65536}{868177}, \, \dots$$
Your task is to find a sequence that does have a closed form expression, for example
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \approx 1.64493407$$
where each term $c_k = \frac{1}{k^2}$.  The sequence must be such that
$$c_k \ge b_k \quad \text{for all} \quad k \ge n$$

Your proof is then based on sums
$$\begin{aligned}
B &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k = B_1 + B_2, \quad
B_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} b_k, \quad
B_2 = \sum_{k=n}^\infty b_k \\
C &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k = C_1 + C_2, \quad
C_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} c_k, \quad
C_2 = \sum_{k=n}^\infty c_k = C - C_1 \\
\end{aligned}$$
where $B$ and $B_2$ are not known exactly, only $B_1$ is known exactly; but $C$, $C_1$, and $C_2$ are known exactly.

Because
$$c_k \ge b_k \quad \text{ for } \quad k \ge n, \quad C_2 \ge B_2$$
and if you prove that
$$B_1 + C_2 \lt 2$$
(which is something you have closed expressions for, if the infinite sum $C$ has a known closed expression), you have proven that
$$B_1 + B_2 = B \lt 2$$

---

The series to focus on those related to the [Riemann Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_constants) at even values:
$$\zeta(n) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^n}$$
The particular one I was thinking of is
$$\zeta(20) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{20}} = \frac{174611 \, \pi^{20}}{1531329465290625} \approx 1.000000953962$$
with $n = 10$.

You see,
$$c_k = \frac{1}{k^{20}} \ge b_k \quad \text{for all} \quad k \ge 10$$
In particular,
$$\begin{aligned}
b_{8} \approx 1.4255 \cdot 10^{-9} \\
b_{9} \approx 2.0321 \cdot 10^{-18} \\
b_{10} \approx 4.1292 \cdot 10^{-36} \\
b_{11} \approx 1.7051 \cdot 10^{-71} \\
c_{8} \approx 8.6736 \cdot 10^{-19} \lt b_{8} \\
c_{9} \approx 8.2253 \cdot 10^{-20} \lt b_{9} \\
c_{10} = 1.0000 \cdot 10^{-20} \gt b_{10} \\
c_{11} \approx 1.4864 \cdot 10^{-21} \gt b_{11} \\
\end{aligned}$$
so we know that
$$\sum_{k=10}^\infty b_k \lt \sum_{k=10}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{20}}$$
and because
$$\sum_{k=10}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{20}} = \frac{174611 \, \pi^{20}}{1531329465290625} - \frac{106662370149283833915501942267857492605696794711249007378798472708401}{106662268397529335923611516553737065783558248857600000000000000000000}$$
we can now calculate the exact sum,
$$\left( \sum_{k=1}^{9} b_k \right) + \left( \sum_{k=10}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{20}} \right) \lt 2$$
and therefore
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k \lt 2$$

Because floating-point numerical calculations do not have enough precision here, I used
$$C = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{20}} = \frac{174611 \, \pi^{20}}{1531329465290625}$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}
C_1 &= \sum_{k=1}^9 \frac{1}{k^{20}} \\
~ &= \frac{106662370149283833915501942267857492605696794711249007378798472708401}{106662268397529335923611516553737065783558248857600000000000000000000} \\
\end{aligned}$$
and
$$\begin{aligned}
B_1 &= \sum_{k=1}^9 b_k \\
~ &= \frac{6494086337598191931522860064611183626609948977242275075491600909077850578669643051565257331009366963694648505112737011786954151363577920417599029974920037685716132002271729535802246547158018}{3247043168799095965761430032305591820008878453592436087532812953641848353074504436078825354366464203708206267593141994294414224765240674053815444080703044269735007407109149741117947776621057} \\
\end{aligned}$$
and verified that $B_1 + C - C_1 \lt 2$ via
$$C + B_1 - C_1 - 2 \lt 0$$
The left side, for evaluation in e.g. Maxima (a free CAS program, wxMaxima being its graphical version), is

```
174611*(%pi^20) / 1531329465290625 - 16492253350531080128239160104845001622128429492012917644483996917752120075662103069882162351389153630866311951764035014010230695125685435114364416532374072620244556261880185006228929268661858194735280962676368978555791749162077866217824355140382739573209517 / 16492237617562539365036586070920801101220100452147363781860837846145943893309011792682018865262830776584392846863644670314594880250899416573838450710644960492510494335952071191890802960534017689711520151393881057079583788816561717064499200000000000000000000
```

and Maxima gives it an approximate value $-6.6613\cdot10^{-16}$, which indeed is less than zero, proving the series sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k \lt 2$.

Comment: How does this answer the question, disclosed in the comment?

Comment: In addition $b_1 = 1/(1/2+1) = 1/(3/2) = 2/3$, not $1/3$

Comment: @CalvinKhor: Thanks for notifying me of the typo, and of the downvote.  In a comment to the question OP mentioned that they asked this question because they need to prove $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k \lt 2$.  To do that, one does not need to know $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k$ nor a closed form expression for $b_k$, only find a series $c_k$ that converges faster than $b_k$ – so $c_k \lt b_k$ for $k \ge n$, with $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} b_k + \sum_{k=n}^\infty c_k \lt 2$ for the proof.  So, this answer tells OP how to answer the underlying question they are trying to solve by asking the question at hand.

Comment: A possible method of proof is not an answer and should be a comment. The series converges incredibly quickly, to what seems numerically like 2. The terms $a_k$ escape the range of numbers expressible by floating point doubles well before 20 terms. The terms are obviously positive, so if one can show that the sum is indeed 2, this gives a proof. Due to the speed of convergence, I think it would be hard to find the sequence $c_k$ as you suggested

Comment: @CalvinKhor: I was hoping I would not need to give the direct answer to OP's underlying question, but it looks I have to, to prove this works.

Comment: @CalvinKhor: Note that if you can show the sum is indeed 2, that *disproves* the underlying claim; which is that $\sum_{k=1}^n b_k \lt 2$ for all $n \gt 1$.  If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b_k = 2$ were true, then my advice would be incorrect; but it isn't, as I showed using $c_k = 1/k^{20}$ above.  Are you sure you haven't just **decided** that the answer to the underlying question is "No" because you **believe** that $\sum b_k = 2$ after a quick numerical test?

Comment: showing that the infinite sum of positive terms is two, proves that the finite sum is always strictly less than 2.

Comment: The sum turns out to be a simple telescoping sum, whose sum is indeed 2, so I'm not sure what your code is doing.

Comment: (1) You said you want zeta at even values but wrote $\zeta(n)$ (2) I have no clue what your $B_1$ is. The sum of the first 9 terms is $\frac{1389373943618}{696834455457}\approx 1.994$. What you claim to be $B_1$ is actually $4\times10^{-35}$ less than $2$. (3) the command you gave doesn't give the negative value you claim, it instead gives me $\displaystyle 1.18160477582517 \cdot 10^{-20}$ which is positive. [Here's my reproduction in jupyter](https://imgur.com/UnUeWaI) (4) Have you seen the simple proof?